# Using "power of two numbers" for length of database columns

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I always try to use power of two numbers to define the length of my database columns, either VARCHAR or CHAR type.

Researching by Internet and debate with partners we do not achieve clarify anything about that, if it take advantaged of full clusters usage or something like that, so the question es simple:

**Is it better use power of two numbers to define the length of the database VARCHAR and CHAR columns?**

Comment: I'd invoke the principal rule of working with databases: Set your database up correctly (indexes, keys, etc) and from there, leave the optimizing to your DBMS. If it's better to use `2^n` as a size, your DBMS *will* do that and you won't have to worry about it yourself.

Comment: Look at e.g. the [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) type in SQL Server. It uses 5, 9, 13 or 17 bytes of storage, depending on precision. If a power of two was desirable, do you not think they'd have done that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it better use power of two numbers to define the length of the database VARCHAR and CHAR columns?

No.

CHAR fields should be used for codes that take up the same number of characters.  For example, CHAR(4) for a four character code column.

Since VARCHAR fields only use the number of characters needed, plus length bytes, you may set your VARCHAR fields to the maximum length for your database.  For example VARCHAR(255) uses only one byte for the length, while VARCHAR(65535) will use two bytes.

Depending on which database system we're talking about, there might be a lower limit for VARCHAR than 65,535.  There is also a limit to how long a row can be in bytes.